# Issue with JavaFX file in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm fairly new to using JavaFX and have been tinkering with it on my own in a few simple projects.

I have to collaborate with a few others for a main project, where I am seeing this conflicting issue:

[image]

I'm having an issue with the src.zip file of javafx. On my standalone projects, I do not encounter this issue. However, since working with others, this error has appeared. Prior to this, I was getting a Kotlin plugin issue, where I had to completely disable Kotlin.

Error:java: C:\Users\nolan\Javalibs\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\src.zip

I'm unsure of what this issue might mean, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is It correct to point a zip as sdk ?

Comment: Well I assume not. Extracting the files fixed the issue (though another one came up). Is there any reason why it was working prior?

Comment: That is really difficult to say beacause I don't know how it was before. Another question, Kotlin is also a part of the IntelliJ platform, it is a sort of plugin the IDE uses to build hte project interrnally, are you sure that is correct to disable it ? (I'm not really sure of this)

Comment: Re-enabling Kotlin didn't bring up the previous issue it had. However, the issue I have now is "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module Tic.Tac.Toe not found"

Comment: The Kotlin plugin is used for developing applications in the [Kotlin programming language](https://kotlinlang.org/) (a JVM language, interoperable with Java); if you aren't using Kotlin in this project it should be safe to disable it. As for the error, can you please show your project setup (e.g. the libraries and JDK)? Also, you might get help from reading [Getting Started with JavaFX 11](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)—specifically the _JavaFX and IntelliJ_ section.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem too and discovered it was because I added the JavaFX 11 SDK to Intellij incorrectly. I initially had the added library point to just the directory /lib. Since this directory includes both the jars and src.zip, Intellij will try to run both and produce the error.

To solve this, when Intellij prompts you to "Select Library Files," you need to explicitly select the files within the /lib directory which will then be added as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OqRz.png). This will also allow proper inspection of the source code without Intellij having to decompile the class file when ctrl + left clicking a class name.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. I extracted the src.zip in the appropriate directory (deleting the zip as well), then had to change my VM Path to include:

```
--module-path "C:\yourpathto\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib;out\production" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I forgot to add `;out\production` to the Module path.

A quick rebuild then solved this issue.

Comment: I don't think the `out/production` should be included, that's the folder where the compiled classes are put by intellij... That folder should be safe to delete and never shipped with the application